# Get real width of element child in directive angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried get the width of child after the view updated.

**My directive:**

```
.directive("scrolltbody", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
            val: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on("ajustarTabelaPedido", function() {
                $timeout(function(){
                    compilar(element, attrs);
                }, 10000);
            });
        }
    }

    function compilar (element, attrs){
        var wTable = angular.element(element).width();
        var th = angular.element(element).find("thead th");
        var tr = angular.element(element).find("tbody tr").get(0);
        var td = angular.element(tr).find("td");

        angular.forEach(th, function (itemTh, indexTh){
            var wElement = angular.element(itemTh).attr("widthscroll");
            var wElementCalc = ((wElement * wTable) / 100);
            /* w = 0 forever*/
            var w = $(tr).find("td").eq(indexTh).outerWidth();
        });
    }
});
```

**My controller:**

```
.controller("PedidoController", function($scope, $pedido) {
    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */

    $scope.buscar = function() {
        $pedido.buscar().then(function(req) {
            $scope.pedido = req;

            /* This dispatch update for directive */
            $scope.$broadcast("ajustarTabelaPedido");
        });
    };

    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="pedido" class="gridbox pedido" scrolltbody val="pedido" style="height: 350px;">
    <thead data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
        <tr>
            <th>Imagem</th>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>
                <span ng-click="ordem.coluna='produto.alavancagem';ordem.reverso=!ordem.reverso">Planejado</span>
                <i ng-show="pedido.erroCaixaria" style="cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-1 justify" title="Regularizar caixaria para mais." ng-click="corrigeCaixaria(pedido, 1)"></i>
                <i ng-show="pedido.erroCaixaria" style="cursor: pointer;" class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-1 justify" title="Regularizar caixaria para menos." ng-click="corrigeCaixaria(pedido, 0)"></i>
            </th>
            <th>Preço Tabela</th>
            <th>Caixaria</th>
            <th>Preço Praticado</th>
            <th>% Desconto</th>
            <th>% Politica Desconto</th>
            <th>Preço c/ Desconto</th>
            <th>Bonificação</th>
            <th>Preço Pedido</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="body" id="pedido-produto">
        <tr ng-repeat="p in pedido.item | orderBy:ordem.coluna:ordem.reverso | filter: itemFilter" >
            <td><img src="<...>" alt="{{p.produto.produto.id | normalizarProdutoSku}}" style="max-height: 50px;" /></td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-1 justify icon-lixeira"></i> {{p.produto.produto.descricao}}</td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="p.produto.alavancagem" />
            </td>
            <td>{{p.produto.precoTabelaView | currency}}</td>
            <td>{{p.produto.gradeMinima}}</td>
            <td>
                <input ng-model="p.produto.precoPraticado"/>
            </td>
            <td><input ng-model="p.produto.percentualDesconto"/></td>
            <td><input ng-model="limitePoliticaDesconto"/></td>
            <td>R$ <input ng-model="p.produto.precoDesconto"/></td>
            <td  ng-class="{'celula-erro' : p.bonificacaoErro}">
                <input ng-model="p.produto.bonificacao" />
            </td>
            <td>{{p.produto.precoDesconto * p.produto.alavancagem | currency}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: What is your HTML looks like?

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Use CSS. Here's one way you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/r9yrM/1/.

Comment: @Alon look now. Updated my question

Comment: @AmyBlankenship, tanks for your sugestion. I need update size th after data renderized. This for create table with sroll and thead fixed.

Comment: @EmirMarques Added my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: @EmirMarques It looks from your code that the "update" is just making sure all your columns are the same size. You can and should do this in CSS, which will simplify your code.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship my code look the width of first row in tbody for others definition

Comment: I think setting the table-layout to fixed should work to resolve that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any `td`s in your table body (that's why the width is always 0), you need to add the cells in your view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in pedido.item | orderBy:ordem.coluna:ordem.reverso | filter: itemFilter" >
    <td>{{ p.anyProperty1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.anyProperty2 }}</td>
    <td>STATIC VALUE</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, i updated my question with correct html. Add +1 for your response

Comment: @EmirMarques Please note that your html adds the `td`s directly inside the `tbody` element, and not the `tr` - is that the same case in your view?

Comment: @EmirMarques Can you try and replace any `angular.element(element)` instances with `$(element)` (native jQuery)?

Comment: Try adding `console.log($(tr).find("td").eq(indexTh));` and see if it output the correct node elements as you expect. I myself not sure where the problem is exactly